# How to make a unit type from the value of particular key in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface with several properties. One of them is `label` with type `string`. Now I want to make a union type based the value I give to `label` in my array objects

```
export interface IChance {
   text: string;
   id: number;
   func: (state: IGameState) => IGameState;
   label: string;
}

export const chances: IChance[] = [
   {
      text: "Advance to Go",
      id: 0,
      func: (state) => movePiece(state, { to: 0 }),
      label: "advance-to-go",
   },
   {
      text: "Advance to Lahore",
      id: 1,
      func: (state) => movePiece(state, { to: 24 }),
      label: "advance-to-lahore",
   },
];

const arr = chances.map((x) => x.label);
export type ChanceLabel = typeof arr[number];
```

`ChanceLabel` is currently of type `string`. But I want its type to be

```
"advance-to-go" | "advance-to-lahore"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you specifically state that `label` is a `string` in `IChance`.

Either you would have to know up front what the allowed labels are and use that in the interface definition, or you could not restrict the type when declaring your array and use `as const` to get all the literal value types.

e.g.

```
const chancesData = [
   {
      text: "Advance to Go",
      id: 0,
      func: (state) => movePiece(state, { to: 0 }),
      label: "advance-to-go",
   },
   {
      text: "Advance to Lahore",
      id: 1,
      func: (state) => movePiece(state, { to: 24 }),
      label: "advance-to-lahore",
   },
] as const;

export const chances: readonly IChance[] = chancesData;
// If you need a mutable array:
// export const chances: IChance[] = [...chancesData];

// You don't need the .map
export type ChanceLabel = (typeof chancesData[number])['label'];
```

(You can even use `ChanceLabel` as the type for `label` in your interface this way.)

Answer (score 0):

if you you wanna add a union type you can use `|` but if you don't know what type will be you can use Generic for example:

```
export interface IChance <T> {
   text: string;
   id: number;
   func: (state: IGameState) => IGameState;
   label: T;
}
const arr:IChance<string | number>[] = [
  {
   text: "bla bla",
   id: 1,
   func: func: (state) => movePiece(state, { to: 0 }),
   label: "string"
 },
 {
   text: "bla bla",
   id: 1,
   func: func: (state) => movePiece(state, { to: 0 }),
   label: 1234
 }
];
```

so here we can change the type of label any time in different places